# Is Google's Protocol Buffers used in large scale production applications?

Tags: messaging, protocol-buffers

Is Google's [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) used in large scale production applications in production?

What is the experience using it?

Comment: What do you mean by protocol buffers? Please add a little bit more information.

Comment: i am referring to:http://eishay.blogspot.com/search/label/protobuf

Comment: I believe Marc Gravell and Jon Skeet (both at Google) are using them?

Comment: Can you please change the title to be a question.

Comment: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Protocol+Buffers/default.aspx

Comment: updated title to be a question

Comment: I think Jon Skeet was the primary developer of protocol buffers but I'm sure he'll be around to say something about it. :)

Comment: Google use it for lots of things internally

Comment: For accuracy, Jon was *not* involved in the original protocol buffers creation; although he owns one (of several) C# ports.

Comment: Just as a sidenote: Blizzard is using protobuf in the netproto of Diablo III which is pretty large scale and (besides some problems till now) it seems to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BTW [Apache ActiveMQ 6](http://activemq.apache.org) will probably be using Protocol Buffers as its default marshalling layer. Early experiences are very favourable; as its easy to have each endpoint on different versions and yet still be able to parse the binary protocol - plus it seems very fast. A great alternative to JSON/XML when you need a performance boost